# ItemAdded event not fire when adding multi items

Tags: sharepoint, event-receiver

I'm using a WebPart to add more than one list item at a time.

And I also have an `EventReceiver` to handle `ItemAdded` event on this list.
The problem is when the WebPart adding items, only first item's added item was caught by the `EventReceiver`.

Don't know the reason why. Can someone help me to explain this? Thanks.

I'm using SharePoint Online.

Answer (score 0):

Can You post some code of your event receiver? Maybe the reason is that there is some kind of error thrown. Since `ItemAdded` is run asynchronously, you won't get any visual notification of error (Except maybe some sandbox quota rising faster, since it's SharePoint Online.).

Comment: I have put a logging function at start of event (this log function won't throw any error), but nothing logged. I also run debugging on localhost and see that sometimes it doesn't run in event receiver.